# Is base64 encoding needed if files are transferred using TCP/IP protocol?

Tags: networking, encoding, base64

I am transferring files over a local network (including binary files), how do I decide if there really is a need of using base64 encoding if I am using TCP/IP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

No, TCP/IP transfers any arbitrary binary data.

Protocols or applications *on top of* TCP/IP (e.g. email) may or may not be able to handle binary data and require some workaround like base 64 encoding.